# Use Android dialog interface on an OpenGL thread?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is it possible to use a pop up dialog on an OpenGL thread?

I currently have a game using the framework I learned from "Beginning android games". But it won't let me implement native android interfaces like the dialog interface. How could I start a new thread to bring up a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                { 
                    //show your dialog here
                }
             }
      );
```